# How do I hide a div in angular based upon document height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Forgive me if this is elsewhere...

I came into a project abandoned half-way through. I've not worked in angular before and need to hide/show a "back to top" button dependent upon whether the document is taller than the viewport. I've tried several different approaches and cannot get anything to work successfully. This is my latest attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($(document).height() > $(window).height()) {
        console.log("document height is greater");
        $('#arrowUp').show();
    } else {
        console.log("window height is lesser");
        $('#arrowUp').show();
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ro4wyox9/

Comment: A snippet of your actual html markup would be helpful to see how you're implementing the angular directives

Comment: Certainly. I should have thought to do such.vThis is my first time using stack overflow in addition to angular.     <div id="topBar" class="flex">
        <a href back-button><img src="img/back-arrow.svg" class="return"></a>
        <h1 id="pageTitle"></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content" ng-view="ngRoute">
    </div>
    <div>
        <a><img ng-show="$(document).height() > $(window).height()" id="arrowUp" class="arrow" src="img/up.svg"></a>
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I highly discourage the mixing of Angular and jQuery - both are DOM manipulation frameworks and they will step on each other causing you endless headaches as you try to troubleshoot various things.

Here is a very contrived example of the "Angular" way of showing or hiding a div based on the height. You should be able to adapt this to suit your needs of showing the arrow based on a difference in window and document heights (it's hard to demonstrate that in the built-in snippet runner).

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.maxHeight = 1200;
    $scope.windowOuterHeight = window.outerHeight;
    $scope.documentHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>
    Enter max height: <input type="text" ng-model="maxHeight">
  </div>
  <div ng-show="windowOuterHeight < maxHeight">
    Window Outer Height is {{windowOuterHeight}}px <br/><br/>
    Document Height is {{documentHeight}}px
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for this! I wasn't aware that they caused issues with one another, but I've had some strange issues with them I have had to work around. I will keep this in mind moving forward. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
<div id="arrowUp" ng-show="$(document).height() > $(window).height()" >
  /\
</div>
```

I would also dismiss the usage of jQuery for a trivial task as fetching those values.

Comment: I appreciate the prompt reply. I would love a solution such as that, but it seems to hide my button. I noticed in my inspector I have the following. I am uncertain if this can help diagnose my issue, though.       [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak, .ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate) {
    display: none !important;
}